# What is dynamic type of object

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, lvalue, subobject

What i think is that dynamic type means dynamically allocated object using `new`. In the following case, do you say `p` points to dynamic type or static type of object? In standard, it doesn't say about dynamic type being dynamic object.

> 1.3.3 - The type of the most derived object (1.8) to which the lvalue denoted
>   by an lvalue expression refers. [Example: if a pointer (8.3.1) p whose
>   static type is "pointer to class B" is pointing to an object of class
>   D, derived from B (clause 10), the dynamic type of the expression *p
>   is "D." References (8.3.2) are treated similarly. ]

Also what does it the following quote mean

> The dynamic type of an rvalue expression is its static type

```
class Base {
    virtual void foo(){}
};

class Derived : public Base {
    void foo(){}
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base *p = &d;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> What i think is that dynamic type means dynamically allocated object
>   using new.

Nope.

The dynamic type is the real type of an object that might be accessed via a reference (pointer included) that point to a base type of its real type.

That is, if we have :

```
class A {

};

class B : public A { };


B l;
A& k = l;
```

Here k is a reference to an object of type A, but the real type of the referred object, its dynamic type, is B.

**Here "dynamic" has the meaning of "known only at run-time".**

Comment: +1, but I think you could make the example even more clear by adding an example that does not use new at all.

Comment: Wouldn't `A &k = B();` suffice?

Comment: In my example, I have virtual functions which means that calls will be resolved at runtime. how does dynamic applies here when there is no dynamic binding?

Comment: @user974191 Do you mean, how is implemented inheritance? Maybe look for "virtual table". In you example the "dynamic type" aka "real type known at runtime" is obviously Derived. However, in some code, you can work with a Base type that in fact is something else without having to know.

Comment: @arne You are using a non-const reference with a temporary. That will not even compile. It would with a const reference if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 6):

The **static type** is the type of the variable, which is the only type known at **compile time** (hence considered static - cannot change). The **dynamic type** is the type of the object that is actually being pointed at **run-time**. Dynamic here means it's only known at run time, which means it might change (namely one variable can point on various objects of various types).

The use of `new` in this content is not relevant, as your own example shows. In your main, the static and dynamic type of `d` is `Derived`, because it's not a pointer or reference. `p`, however, has a static type of `Base`, but in your code, the dynamic type would be `Derived`.

Comment: But `*p`  is not a variable, it's an expression.

Answer (score 5):

In a statically typed language, such as C++ or Java for example, `static` may refer to the information known at compilation time while `dynamic` refers to the information known at runtime.

For example:

```
struct Base { virtual std::string name() const { return "Base"; } };

struct Derived: Base { std::string name() const { return "Derived"; } };

void print(Base const& b) { std::cout << b.name() << "\n"; }
```

In the `print` method, the `static` type of `b` is `Base const&`. Therefore, the compiler will check that all methods called exist in the context of a `Base` object.

However, when execution comes, the call to `name`, as the method is virtual, is performed with regard to the `dynamic` type of the object:

- this may be `Base`
- this may be `Derived`
- this may be another derived class from `Base` that we know not yet

Therefore, in the following example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc == 1) {
    Base base;
    print();
  } else {
    Derived derived;
    print(derived);
  }
};
```

- The `static` and `dynamic` type of `base` is `Base` and `derived` is `Derived`.
- In the `print` method, the `static` type of `b` is `Base` (always)
- Depending on the number of arguments, the `dynamic` of `b` is either `Base` or `Derived`

It is a current mistake to assume that polymorphism is necessarily based on dynamic memory allocation, but the two concepts, while not orthogonal, can be used without one another in some conditions.