# Why is typeid always returning false?

Tags: c++, typeid, typeinfo

So I have to make a text based video game for a project. I made a class called "tile" and then a subclass called "wall." I then made an array of tiles shown below. The center tile, B2 is a wall. When I compare `typeid(B2)==typeid(wall)` it returns false even though tile B2 is of type wall. The class, "fighter" has an x and a y component.

```
  //Initiate map
    const int rows = 3;
    const int cols = 3;
    tile A1, A2, A3, B1, B3, C1, C2, C3;
    fighter wizard(1, 2, 6, ft::mage, 100);
    C3 = tile(wizard, "There's all this magic stuff everywhere.");
    wall B2= wall("A wall blocks your path.");
    tile map[rows][cols] =  {{A1, A2, A3},
                             {B1, B2, B3},
                             {C1, C2, C3}};
...

fighter player1(0, 0, 0, ft::warrior);

...

string input = "";
while(input!="quit")
{ 
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "left") {
        if (typeid(map[player1.y][player1.x - 1]) == typeid(wall))
            cout << map[player1.y][player1.x - 1].scene;
```

Comment: So, why do you think `map[player1.y][player1.x - 1]` is a wall? I'd say it's a pure tile (even if B2 is a wall, because object copy => **slicing**)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: @deviantfan is on the right track. You're creating a 2D array of `tile` objects and you're going to have a problem when you try to copy a `wall` into the array. I'm guessing you're intending to have an array of `Tile*` types which could be point to `Tile*` or `Wall*` types, since `Tile*` is the base class.

Comment: (and if you go this way, make sure your classes have vtables, else typeid won't be too happy with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tile map[rows][cols]
```

Stores tile objects. If you were to inspect these objects you will find that they are of class `tile`. Not the type of the original `B2` object, `wall`. So

```
if (typeid(map[player1.y][player1.x - 1]) == typeid(wall))
```

will always compare `tile == wall`.

If you are interested in preserving the dynamic type you need to use (smart) pointers or any way that references the original object. These objects needs to have a dynamic type/have virtual functions.

See also [What is dynamic type of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649649/what-is-dynamic-type-of-object)