# Dynamic type of an expression dealing with a base class subobject

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, lvalue, subobject

I am asking the question again because the [only other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7649649/963864) that is like this is approaching 10 years old, and contains incorrect information about expressions involving base class subobjects:

[[defns.dynamic.type]](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.dynamic.type) defines the dynamic type of a glvalue as:

> type of the most derived object to which the glvalue refers

A glvalue only refers to at most one object, and since "most derived object" as defined by [[intro.object]  p6](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#6) essentially is:

> A complete object, a data member, or an array element of class type, or, an object of a non-class type is called a most derived object.

If the glvalue does not refer to a most derived object, then would the dynamic type be undefined?

Also, I know the intended effect of dynamic type of an expression is: for a glvalue expression `E` that refers to an object of type `B`, which is a base class subobject of an object of type `D`, where `B` is a base class of `D`, to get the type `D` from `E`, however, I do not see how the current wording accomplishes that, or even needs to, since references/pointers of base class type bound to derived class type will always refer to the base class subobject. As far as I can tell, a case where the type of the expression and the type of the object that it refers to would never occur.

Comment: what is "the only other question" ? A question containing wrong information is kind of natural, what about the answers?

Comment: @formerly The answers are incorrect, they state that for this snippet: `const T& a = U();` the reference is bound to the object of type `U`, when infact it is bound to the base class subobject of the temporary object that is creates (assuming `U is derived from `T`)

Comment: @KrystianS: "*when infact it is bound to the base class subobject of the temporary object that is creates (assuming `U` is derived from `T`) *" Can you cite where that actually is said in the standard? Because that's not how references work. As far as the standard is concerned, `a` is a reference to a `U`, with the type `T`.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas see http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5

Comment: Can you add a link to "the only other question"?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649649/what-is-dynamic-type-of-object and I like your username :)

Answer (score 5):

> If the glvalue does not refer to a most derived object, then would the dynamic type be undefined?

It always does. Hence the "then" part does not apply.

#### Update in response to comment

Given

```
struct foo { };
struct bar : foo { };
const foo& a = bar(); a;
```

What is the dynamic type of `a`?

The answer is found in the [page you linked to in your post](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.dynamic.type):

> [ *Example:* If a pointer `p` whose static type is “pointer to class `B`” is pointing to an object of class `D`, derived from `B`, the dynamic type of the expression `*p` is “`D`”. References are treated similarly. *— end example* ]

The dynamic type of `a` is `bar`, not `foo`.

Comment: Flashbacks to Propositional Logic 101 and material implication.

Comment: @Eljay, I wasn't aware of the subject. Interesting subject to occupy one's grey matter. https://www.iep.utm.edu/prop-log/.

Comment: @R Sahu Does it? Take this for example: `struct foo { }; struct bar : foo { }; const foo& a = bar(); a; // a refers to the foo subobject of the bar temporary, so the object the glvalue refers to is not a complete object, nor a member, nor an array element, nor an object of non-class type, so how could the dynamic type be the type of the most derived object, if the object that a refers to is not one`

Comment: @KrystianS, in that case, the dynamic type of `a` is `bar&`.

Comment: @R Shau I don't think so, as dictated by [expr.type] p1, expressions that denote references are adjusted to denote the object denoted by the reference, and the type of the expression is adjusted as well.

Comment: @KrystianS, I am not finding that language in C++11, C++14, or C++17. Please post a link, if you have one. Thanks.

Comment: @KrystianS: "*expressions that denote references are adjusted to denote the object denoted by the reference, and the type of the expression is adjusted as well.*" Then explain why the [strict aliasing rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#8.1) has an explicit allowance for accessing a derived class object through a pointer/reference to a base class? If C++ thought of references to base class subjects as identical to references to any object of that type, then there would be no need for such a provision.

Comment: @KrystianS: [expr.type]/1 doesn't say that the reference suddenly becomes a `T` which behaves identically to any other `T`; only that the type of the reference becomes `T` rather than `T&`.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas The reference does not change, but the expression does.  Given `T& t = u;` the expression `t` will be of type `T`, and will refer denote to object denoted by `u`.

Comment: @KrystianS: "*The reference does not change, but the expression does.*" No, the *type* of the expression changes. The expression is still a reference; it merely has the type `T` as far as any subsequent processing goes.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I don't know why that exception is there, however I can tell you that when binding a reference to an object of derived class type, where the type refered to is a base class of the object being bound to, the reference is bound to the base class subobject, not the complete object of derived type. The same applies to pointers.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas It does change what the expression denotes, as stated here http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#1.sentence-2

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Can we agree now that references, when bound to an object of a derived type, will bind to the base class subobject?

Comment: @NicolBolas Then why did the so called strict aliasing rule had an item about aggregates? Your meta argument is extremely weak.

Comment: It makes **no sense** to say that any ptr must points to the complete object. What would a derived to base conversion even do? Nothing? That's absurd on its face; even if the std text says so, it should be disregarded. Many times the text contained absurd statements, and never these patently false statements were allowed to shape the language.

Comment: @curiousguy, It makes sense to me that the dynamic type, not the static type, of the object that the pointer points to is the type of the complete object.

Comment: @RSahu Yes it's the dynamic type but you must admit that a ptr points to base class subobject for C++ to make sense, or there is no derived to base real conversion!

Comment: @curiousguy, agreed. Completely.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be able to argue that this is a wording defect, but it would be pedantic because the intent is already clear. Instead of:

> type of the most derived object to which the glvalue refers

you might imagine that the definition reads:

> type of the most derived object of the object to which the glvalue refers

Comment: Most derived object isn't a property of an object, but rather something that an object can be, so I don't see how that wording would make sense... Either way, I don't see a single case where the type of an expression would differ from the object it denotes.

Comment: @KrystianS: "*Either way, I don't see a single case where the type of an expression would differ from the object it denotes.*" Then that right there is the problem, because that's how pointers and references work in C++. You have a reference to an object. The type of that reference can be *different* from the type of the object (referencing a derived class through a reference of a base class type). But you're *always* referencing the complete object.

Comment: @KrystianS You should interpret "the most derived object of the object" as "the unique object that is a most derived object and either is the object in question or contains it as a base class subobject".

Comment: @Nicol Bolas When you bind a reference of type `B` to an object of type `D`, where `B` is a base class of `D`, the reference binds to the base class subobject of the object of type `D`, that base class subobject being the type of the base class, `B`, not the complete object of type `D`. See http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5 "[...] or, in either case, to the appropriate base class subobject of the object.". The same applies to pointers, there is a standard pointer conversion that is applied, see [conv.ptr]

Comment: @KrystianS "_the reference binds to the base class subobject of the object of type D_" That goes w/o saying! C++ wouldn't make much sense if ptr and ref to subobjects did not actually refer to subobjects.

Comment: @curiousguy He didn't seem to agree :P

Comment: @KrystianS At some point, I say whatever the std says, ppl know intuitively what is correct. **In no case in history were the words of the std allowed to shape the reality of C++.** The intuition of ppl who know what they are talking about shape C++. The words and the committee members try to keep up with reality. Not the other way around, despite what many ppl here try to insinuate.

Comment: @KrystianS Did this answer fully address your question?

Comment: @Brian well, in a way yes. I submitted a issue on the repo, and also wrote up some wording to fix it - hopefully I can take care of it editorially.